# Create zip from array list of elements, stored in different folders

Tags: php, zip

I got a loop with whom I write data in a table, included urls of files I've to zip.
During the loop I put the url in an array.
At the end of table I would have a button, giving me the zip of all files.

I'm in a wordpress site, PHP 5 and Linux.

During loop I save url file here with its path

```
if (file_exists($file_letttut)) {
    $nameAndCode['zipp'] = "http://mypath/to/".$file_letttut;
    $namesArray[] = $nameAndCode;}
```

I tried different codes to zip, I write here the easier

```
$zip = new ZipArchive;
$zip_name = "zippot.zip"; // Zip name
$res = $zip->open($zip_name, ZipArchive::CREATE);
if ($res === TRUE) {
    foreach($namesArray as $key => $value) { 
        $nomefile = basename($namesArray[$key][zipp].$value);
        $nomefile = str_replace('Array', '', $nomefile);
        $nomecompleto = str_replace('Array', '', $namesArray[$key][zipp].$value);
        $zip->addFile($nomecompleto, $nomefile);
    }
    $zip->close();
    echo 'ok';
} else {
    echo 'failed';
}
if(file_exists($zip_name)) {
    echo "yes";die;
    header('Content-type: application/zip');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$res.'"');
    readfile($res);
    unlink($res);
} else { 
    echo "zip not created";die; 
}
```

> $zip_name doesn't exist...

Where do I fail?
Should I've to copy files to a folder before?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you show the exact error you are receiving?

Comment: I don't obtain any zip... neither in the root, neither directly in header.
I obtain the echo with "zip not created"